# Python matplotlib plotting after date

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having an issue plotting after a date has been plotted. the code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import style

x = [735412.0, 735503.0, 735594.0, 735685.0]

y =['0.0', '16961000000.0', '29030000000.0', '32504000000.0']

z = ['100000', '200000000000', '3000000000000', '400000000000']



# plt.plot_date(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')

plt.plot(y,z) # this does not print if above line is uncommented

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # turns bottom dates at angle

plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
L

Comment: You don't have any dates to plot.  I believe `plot_date()` will expect the first argument to be a list of datetime objects.

Comment: @Scott, no, the numbers in `x` are interpreted somehow as dates (hours since some reference or so, I am sure).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your "numbers" in `y` are actually **strings**. You would need to convert them to float using `np.array(y, float)` to use them on an axis.

But did you really intend to `plt.plot(y,z)` in the **same figure** as the others? The values in `y` are not dates/times of any kind, so probably not.

I suspect this should be a new figure, so you need to start a new figure with `plt.figure()` before you plot `y` vs `z`:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y,z)
```

and drop the `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` after that.

Comment: THanks all, it looks like it makes no difference whether y is a list of strings of floats, they can be plotted individually with no problem. What I am trying to accomplish is to plot overlapping lines on the same figure like the following:x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,3,4]
z = [5,4,3]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,z)
plt.show()

Comment: In that case you just have typo (`y,z` instead of the correct `x,z`).